# Binary search tree output file is not the expected output data

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, c-strings

Okay so I am creating a Binary Search Tree that reads in strings and stores them in the tree. I am trying to confirm that each string has it's own node and each string is actually being read in. When my program is run, I believe it is creating seven nodes, one for each of the strings in the input file. So I created an Output file that prints the string that was just read to make sure each string is being stored in a node. There are seven strings in my input file :

```
bring
awake
anger
carry
global
fixed
halt
```

Here is the code for my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 15

typedef struct treeNode{
  char string[MAXLEN+1];
  struct treeNode *left;
  struct treeNode *right;
}treeNode;

treeNode * insert(treeNode *node, char s[MAXLEN]){
  puts("running insert");
  if(node == NULL){
    node = (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    strncpy(node -> string, s, MAXLEN);
    node -> left = NULL;
    node -> right = NULL;
  }

  else if(strcmp(node->string, s)>0){
    node -> right = insert(node->right, s);
  }
  else if(strcmp(node->string, s)<0){
    node -> left = insert(node->left, s);
  }
  else if(strcmp(node->string, s) == 0){
    node -> left = insert(node->left, s);
  }

  return node;

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  treeNode *root = NULL;

  FILE *ifp;
  FILE *ofp;
  char s[MAXLEN+1];

  if(argc != 3){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[1]); exit(1);
  }

  if((ifp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file: %s\n", argv[2]); exit(1);
  }

  ofp = fopen("output.txt", "w+");

  while(fscanf(ifp, "%s\n", &s) != EOF){
    root = insert(root, s);
    fprintf(ofp, "%s\n", root->string);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And this is what the output file looks like after running the program:

```
bring
bring
bring
bring
bring
bring
bring
```

Now there are seven strings in each file so i am assuming each one is read. But how can I know if my program successfully created a node for each string?
How can I fix the problem? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Learn to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line while keeping an eye on the involved variables and their values.

Comment: Oh and be careful with that `strncpy` call, if the input string is exactly `MAXLEN` characters long (or longer, you have no check for that) then the string terminator will not be added.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Since OP has allocated `MAXLEN+1` chars to hold his string, setting `node->string[MAXLEN+1] = 0` would probably be a better way to guarantee that his string is null terminated.

Comment: @Degustaf close, but `temp->string[MAXLEN] = 0;` is the proper truncation suffix after that `strncpy`. Using `MAXLEN+1` will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: May as well fix this: `while(fscanf(ifp, "%s\n", &s) != EOF)` should be `while(fscanf(ifp, "%s\n", s) == 1)`. Further, your read-loop always outputs your root node, which never changes after the initial insertion of the first word, as you have no rebalancing algorithms.

Comment: @WhozCraig `char s[MAXLEN]` is passed in and is used to populate `node->string[MAXLEN+1]`.  This means OP can copy `MAXLEN` chars over, and then have room left in `node->string` to add a null terminator.

Comment: @Degustaf `char s[IDontCareWhatThisIs]` is the parameter. `s` is converted to `char*` on passage. The *caller* dictates the size of the source buffer, which for whatever reason the OP has chosen not to pass that magnitude with the insertion parameters. The source is the caller's buffer in `main` is `MAXLEN+1`., which means the maximum addressable element is `MAXLEN`. The target is the string member, and it is `MAXLEN+1`, meaning the max addressable element is MAXLEN.

Comment: Meanwhile, the reason you see the same value printed is because all you're asking to print is the root of the tree repeatedly while you read in the content. Once you store the first element as root that never changes. You have no rebalancing algorithms in your insertion logic. The first insertion is `bring`. From then on each time you `fprintf(ofp, "%s\n", root->string);` in your read loop you're always going to get the **same** element; the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FULL CODE repaired : http://pastebin.com/5BTnxTcd
OTHER optimizing code , leave it to you.

It seem your problem is return. It need to be like this, because you need to return root of tree->

```
treeNode * insert(treeNode *node, char s[MAXLEN]){
  puts("running insert");
  if(node == NULL){
    node = (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    strncpy(node -> string, s, MAXLEN);
    node -> left = NULL;
    node -> right = NULL;
  }

  else if(strcmp(node->string, s)>0){
    node -> right = insert(node->right, s);
  }
  else if(strcmp(node->string, s)<0){
    node -> left = insert(node->left, s);
  }
  else if(strcmp(node->string, s) == 0){
    node -> left = insert(node->left, s);
  }
 return node;
}
```

**EDIT: ** It seem you have problem also with `argv`, `argv[0]` is name of program

```
fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[1]); exit(1);
```

need to be

```
fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]); exit(1);
```

EDIT**EDIT** :
You need function to do recursive process to tree, and output first left side then right and it will be:

```
void treeprint( treeNode *node , FILE *OUTPUT_FILE)
{
  if ( node != NULL)
    {
      treeprint(node->left , OUTPUT_FILE);
      fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE , "%s" , node->string);
      treeprint(node->right, OUTPUT_FILE);
    }
}
```

and call after `while` loop , and call function like `treeprint(root, ofp);`.

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested to the insert file but I am getting the same output... Is there a problem with how I am calling the insert function in main?

Comment: U have problem with this line , i waill now edit that line -> fprintf(ofp, "%s\n", root->string);

Comment: That is it i try code full, and it work i now set code full for u.

Comment: Wow thank you! I believe this confirms that all of the words are in the tree. Each word is listed in the output.

Comment: And it is sorted. :) U may want to add some int in struct like count and increment it, if it encounters in insert function the same strings.

Comment: Yes you are right, I need to count things like the height and number of node/leaves in the subtrees so this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with how you are printing.  In your insert algorithm, you never modify the string in the node.  But, when you print, you are printing the root each time.  So, you have a couple of choices:

1. Use a debugger as @JoachimPileborg suggested.
2. print the input string `s` to see if it was read from the input properly.
3. Write another function to traverse your tree and print out the string in each node as you go.  This is the most involved, but is likely to be useful later.

Comment: Upticked, straight up and to the point. Thankfully for #3, a traversal [isn't overtly complicated](http://ideone.com/lQ9lN3).

Answer (score 0):

Lets come to the issue you are facing: 
You want to know if your program successfully created a node for each string or not. There are more than one ways to tackle this problem. The easiest way is to print out the value of the node when it is actually being created. Thus your code will look something like:

```
 treeNode * insert(treeNode *node, char s[MAXLEN]){
  puts("running insert");
  if(node == NULL){
   node = (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
   strncpy(node -> string, s, MAXLEN);
   node -> left = NULL;
   node -> right = NULL;

   **printToFile( root->string );**
  }

  else if(strcmp(node->string, s)>0){
    node -> right = insert(node->right, s);
  }
  else if(strcmp(node->string, s)<0){
   node -> left = insert(node->left, s);
  }
  else if(strcmp(node->string, s) == 0){
   node -> left = insert(node->left, s);
  }

   return node;
 }
```

Here is helper function for printing into file:

```
  File* ofp; // Need to be declared globally or pass in functions as  parameters

  void openWritableFile()
  {
    ofp = fopen("output.txt", "w+");
  }
  void printToFile( char* data )
  {
    fprintf(ofp, "%s\n", data );
  }
```

Another approach would be to travel the whole tree using tree traversal algorithms such as in-order, post-order or pre-order, but only after creation of the complete tree.

Here is how you can do inorder traversal by using your root element and thus printing contents of the tree:

```
 void inorder(struct root* node)
{
   if (root == NULL)
      return;
    inorder(root->left)
    printToFile( root->string );
    inorder(root->right);
}
```

You can learn about tree traversal here: [Tree Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)